# Program why does not take any input

Tags: python

My code is:

```
print("welcome into my program")
print("you want to know the percentage then type yes")
o=input
if str(o)=='yes':
    t=input("enter the total marks\n")
    x=input("enter your marks\n")
    p=(int(x)*100)/int(t)
    print("This is your percentage =",p)
else:
    print("bye :)")
```

**output:**

```
welcome into my program
you want to know the percentage then type yes
bye :)
```

I search on it but I did not find any thing. When I try to run my program it just ignores my input line and goes ahead to print from the `else` block.

Comment: "`input`" is the name of a built-in function. `o=input` just gives the function another name, but does _not_ call it because there's no `()` suffix.

Comment: Whenever you are confused by why an `if` block isn't entered, the first thing you should do is check the actual value. Here, if you had tried for example to `print(o)` right before the `if`, you would have seen something that would hopefully have given you a better idea of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
print("welcome into my program")
print("you want to know the percentage then type yes")
o = input()
if str(o) == 'yes':
    t = input("enter the total marks\n")
    x = input("enter your marks\n")
    p = (int(x) * 100) / int(t)
    print("This is your percentage =", p)
else:
    print("bye :)")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the `input` function. Change that line to `o = input()`

Answer (score 0):

You just need open and close parentheses after the call to the `input()` function on your 3rd line (source: [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)).